# Is it possible to display images in SwiftUI `.alert`?

Tags: swiftui

`Alert(title: <#T##Text#>, message: <#T##Text?#>, ...)` inits take title and messages only as `Text` not a `View`. But `Text` is capable of displaying images. So why can't I display images as a title or a message?

Here is a small playground with an alert that tries to show an image as its title, but shows just some empty space. Although no errors appear.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(Image(systemName: "info.circle")) // Just to ensure `Text` can display `Image`
            Button("Show Alert") {
                self.showAlert = true
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text(Image(systemName: "info.circle")),
                      message: Text("Alert message").bold() /* bold is not working */,
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 600) // Sorry about it
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(stringLiteral: "iPhone 7")))
//`.previewdevice` has no effect in playground
```

Comment: If it mentioned Text in interface contract, then you must provide Text, but not Image.

Comment: I just don't understand why not to restrict to `String` then, @Asperi? Or extend to a `View` and allow all kind of Content. `Text` modifiers have no effect anyway here too. No control over bolds, italics or fonts.

Comment: @PaulB The `Text` type encapsulates localization semantics (via the `LocalizedStringKey` init option) which is, I think, why the `Alert` interface specifies `Text` input rather than more generic `String` input.